# MySQL multiple SELECT statements in one query

Tags: mysql

I'm storing some information in a MySQL table including a date without time.
The date format is a string looking like this: "25.08.2016" (Day.Month.Year).

I want to select the top 50 records from a table descending by a column, but I only want to display the rows with a specific column entry (date).

It is a ranking system and I want to update inactive people.

I would need to combine these 3 queries:

```
SELECT * FROM `rank` ORDER BY `rank`.`Score` DESC LIMIT 0 , 50;
SELECT * FROM `rank` WHERE NOT (`TimeStamp1` = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d.%m.%Y') OR `TimeStamp1` = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%d.%m.%Y'));
UPDATE `rank` SET `inactive` = '1';
```

1. Selecting the top 50 people.
2. Selecting the inactive people of the first query.
3. Updating the people to inactive.

The most `Score` is rank 1 and that's why I need DESC, I only want to mark the top 50 people as inactive nothing below, below 50 those people are irrelevant that's why I can't use a statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `rank` WHERE NOT (`TimeStamp1` = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d.%m.%Y') OR `TimeStamp1` = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%d.%m.%Y')) ORDER BY `rank`.`Score` DESC LIMIT 0 , 50
```

Yes, it would select 50 rows but not the top 50.

BTW I'm doing it in php.
And I could solve the problem by fetching:

```
SELECT * FROM `rank` ORDER BY `rank`.`Score` DESC LIMIT 0 , 50;
```

Then storing the Accound IDs  to an array, then query:

```
SELECT * FROM `rank` WHERE NOT (`TimeStamp1` = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d.%m.%Y') OR `TimeStamp1` = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%d.%m.%Y')) ORDER BY `rank`.`Score` DESC LIMIT 0 , 50;
```

And compare the Accound IDs to the other result, when no match is found I just break the loop.

Can't I just do it with pure MySQL? Can't I query a thing and then filter the results?

Please help me, any more questions?

Comment: Use a date field this will make life a lot easier

Comment: I would use a date field when I would be able to convert my already existing format "25.08.2016" to the date field thing, I can't just truncate 70.000 rows.. my data is up to 3 years old. Anyways that's not the point, I need to select 50 rows and then compare a single clumn, then update the left over. Example.: I buy 50 apples and 10 of them are squishy but 5 of them can still be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my Answer.

```
UPDATE rank AS target
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT w.id
    FROM rank AS w
    INNER JOIN rank AS e ON e.id = w.id
    WHERE (w.`TimeStamp1` = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d') OR w.`TimeStamp1` = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY),'%Y-%m-%d')) 
    ORDER BY w.`Score` DESC
    LIMIT 50
) AS source ON source.id = target.id
SET inactive = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I have two options I can learn from. =)

Answer (score 1):

One way of executing queries sequentially is by using **transaction**.
But that won't combine your queries into one.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SELECT * 
FROM `rank` 
ORDER BY `rank`.`Score` DESC LIMIT 0 , 50;

SELECT * 
FROM `rank` 
WHERE NOT (`TimeStamp1` = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d.%m.%Y') OR `TimeStamp1` = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%d.%m.%Y'));

UPDATE `rank` SET `inactive` = '1';


COMMIT;
```

Comment: I've seen something like SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM) as aliastwo) as aliasone. But I don't know how to use it for my statements.

Select 50 apples -> Select squishy apples -> Update squishy apples

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this might be a combination of the three queries:

```
update rank r
set r.inactive = 1
from
(select a.account_id from rank a
join (select account_id from rank order by rank.score desc limit 0, 50) b on (a.account_id = b.account_id )
where (a.`TimeStamp1` = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d.%m.%Y') OR a.`TimeStamp1` = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%d.%m.%Y'))) l
where r.account_id = l.account_id
```

Let me know if anything fails :)

Edit: swapped rank_id with account_id

Comment: Thank you very much this is it! But it is giving me the opposit result - sorry my bad.. WHERE NOT (a. ... thank you so much!

This thing is so confusing, isn't there a website with a little tool which creates this for me :)